# Implementing convenience methods that use Controller protected methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, base-class

Is there any way I can implement a convenience method that uses a Controller's protected method(s) without using a base controller, which is recommended against [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119341/178757)?  For example, I want to return an `ActionResult` based on whether a `returnUrl` query string param has been passed.  What I really want is an extension method like this:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions {
    public static ActionResult RedirectReturnUrlOrDefaultAction(this Controller thisController, string returnUrl, string defaultAction) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && thisController.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
            return thisController.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else {
            return thisController.RedirectToAction(defaultAction);
        }
    }
}
```

So that I could then say this:

```
return this.RedirectReturnUrlOrDefaultAction(Request.QueryString["returnUrl"], "Index");
```

... from within a `Controller`.  But of course that extension method doesn't compile because for some reason, methods like `Redirect` are `protected internal` (why are they `protected internal`, by the way?)

Is there a decent way I can do this without using a base controller?  If not, might this be one good reason to actually use a base controller, or is there something flawed with my design?

Comment: While I don't believe it's possible to access any non-public method/properties from extension methods, would it be possible for you to to return `new RedirectResult` instead of `controller.Redirect`?

Comment: Hmm, it may well be.  But what about the `RedirectToAction`?

Comment: You might be able to use `UrlHelper.Action` to determine the URL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504960.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions {
    public static ActionResult RedirectReturnUrlOrDefaultAction(this Controller controller, Func<string, ActionResult> returnUrlRedirectAction, Func<ActionResult> defaultAction) {
        string returnUrl = controller.Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && controller.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
            return returnUrlRedirectAction(returnUrl);
        }
        else {
            return defaultAction();
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used in the controller as:

```
return this.RedirectReturnUrlOrDefaultAction(ret => Redirect(ret), () => RedirectToAction("Index"));
```

Comment: Yep, calling back the controller.  Not bad, although wouldn't be necessary if `RedirectToAction` etc. didn't have stupid privacy restrictions.

Comment: OK, I came up with this solution based on yours: http://pastebin.com/fcMuXbGb - if you replace your solution with this one, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.