# How to replace a base controller with MVC ActionFilter (or something else)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

I'm trying to improve my MVC design. On every page, I need to read a cookie and set an User object with various values based on that (not authentication related).

What I currently do is have all controllers inherit from a BaseController, and use a User object in the BaseController.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected User thisUser { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
         // ... read cookie, set values of thisUser
    }
}
```

Is this a bad design ? I like it for only defining `User` once, but I've read the answer on [What are good candidates for base controller class in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119206/what-are-good-candidates-for-base-controller-class-in-asp-net-mvc) , and I'm open to redoing it if there's a better way. But I definitely don't want an approach that means repeating `User thisUser = new User();` on each controller, and I can't see how I can implement like that without a base controller. I can't find a good example that uses ActionFilters this way.

I'm not using a DI framework yet, but will if it solves the problems. If it means passing `User` as a parameter into each controller or action, I'm not sure that's an improvement in the DRY stakes though.

I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Create the interface

```
interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

CustomPrincipal

```
public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInRole(string role) { return false; }

    public CustomPrincipal(string email)
    {
        this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(email);
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

CustomPrincipalSerializeModel - for serializing custom information into userdata field in FormsAuthenticationTicket object.

```
public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

LogIn method - setting up a cookie with custom information

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password))
{
    var user = userRepository.Users.Where(u => u.Email == viewModel.Email).First();

    CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
    serializeModel.UserId = user.Id;
    serializeModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    serializeModel.LastName = user.LastName;

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
             1,
             viewModel.Email,
             DateTime.Now,
             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
             false,
             userData);

    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
    HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Global.asax.cs - Reading cookie and replacing HttpContext.User object, this is done by overriding PostAuthenticateRequest

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

        CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
        newUser.UserId = serializeModel.UserId;
        newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
        newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;

        HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
    }
}
```

Access in Razor views

```
@((User as CustomPrincipal).Id)
@((User as CustomPrincipal).FirstName)
@((User as CustomPrincipal).LastName)
```

for complete answer use this topic : 
[ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

Comment: +1. But I would provide a static getter in my `CustomPrincipal` which makes the cast for me (`public static CustomPrincipal Current get { return (CustomPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal; } }`) so that I only have to use `CustomPrincipal.Current.LastName`