# How to Apply Override Method only once for all controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement following logic:

Whenever a new user is created, a default hardcoded password would be assigned. If the new created user logged in, the system would FORCE the user to change their default password

I have successfully achieved the logic above with this code in my controllers:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Check if authenticated
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Equals("/Account/ChangePassword") && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Equals("/Account/LogOff"))
        {
            //Get user Data
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
            if (currentUser.GetPassword().Equals("password"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                       new RouteValueDictionary 
                                        { 
                                            { "controller", "Account" }, 
                                            { "action", "ChangePassword" } 
                                        });
            }
        }
    }
```

However, now i have to copy paste this code to all of my controllers. Does this disrespect the DRY principle in mvc3 ?

If Yes, Where or how should i place this code so it can be globally implemented to all of my controllers?
I tried to paste it in Global.asax but i got an error that said "No Suitable Method Found to Override"

Comment: Create a base controller that inherits Controller and have this method defined there. Then have all your other controllers inherit the base controller class you created.

Comment: Thank you very much...!!! i didn't know it's this simple.... :D

Comment: This also could be achieved using a global ActionFilter

Comment: Where do i put my actionfilter class? is it in controller?

Comment: Yikes!  You're using cleartext or reversible passwords?  I hope you have a good excuse to give when your site is hacked and you leak all those passwords onto the internet.

Comment: Erik has a good point. Hard coding a password isn't a very good solution. Creating a random password would be a better solution (although there are probably solutions that are better still). It would also be better if you compare hashes of passwords rather than actual clear text.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, i will implement more secure solutions...!!! =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previously described by others in the comment section, you could do this using ***base controller*** or using ***action filter***.

For now, you may consider using actionfilter creating like this.

```
public class YourActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}


     [YourActionFilter]
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
               return View();
          }

          public ActionResult About()
          {
               return View();
          }
     }
```

More details you can find in [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Answer (score 0):

Use a global filter. Here is an example of an action filter.

```
public class ForceLoginActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Check if authenticated
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Equals("/Account/ChangePassword") && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Equals("/Account/LogOff"))
        {
            //Get user Data
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
            if (currentUser.GetPassword().Equals("password"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                       new RouteValueDictionary
                                        {
                                        { "controller", "Account" },
                                        { "action", "ChangePassword" }
                                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new ForceLoginActionFilter());
    }
}
```

Reference: [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx)

> **NOTE:** [Never use a base controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119341/181087). This will almost always lead to creating a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) that is difficult to maintain.