# ASP.NET Core MVC application dependency injection issue when using BaseController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently i tried to create a MVC application using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and i had some values defined in appsettings.json,

```
"MySettings": {
"WebApiBaseUrl": "http://localhost:6846/api/"
}
```

In order to read these values i have added

```
services.Configure<MySettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

above line in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs
and in my home controller i have added

```
private readonly IOptions<MySettingsModel> appSettings;
public HomeController(IOptions<MySettingsModel> app)
{
   appSettings = app;
}
```

MySettingsModel class is just a model with property same as key define in appsettings.json.
by this method i'm able to read the value of this key.

Now my issue is that i want to use this key in many controllers so i don't want to repeat this code in every controller so what i did was i created a BaseConntroller, added its constructor and i got my values there. But when i inherit other controllers with my BaseController , it throws me an error and tells me to generate it's constructor, so basically it tells me to add constructor in every controller which is what i wanted to avoid.

How can i achieve this?

You can see the image for the error
[image: This is the error that i get]

And these are the potential fixes that it shows me.

[image: Potential fixes]

Comment: Having the constructor is how the framework will inject the settings into the derived class. No getting around that without using an service locator anti-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just basic C# inheritance. Derived classes must re-implement constructors on base classes (at least the ones you want or need). The only exception is the empty constructor, which is implicit. In other words, you simply need:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IOptions<MySettingsModel> app)
        : base(app)
    {
    }
```

And, of course, you need to change the accessibility of the base class field to `protected` instead of `private`. Otherwise, derived classes will not be able to access it.

Of course, this doesn't really save you that much. However, there's no free lunch here. Like I said, this is a limitation of C#, itself, so you have no choice. Although, it's worth mentioning, that while this can sometimes be annoying, it's actually a kind of useful feature of C#. You can look at any class and see exactly what constructors it has available, without having to trace down all its ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a good solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48886242/2060975

I am mostly using this method.

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public abstract class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    private IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    protected IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings => _appSettings ?? (_appSettings = (IOptions<AppSettings>)this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<AppSettings>)));
...
}
```

I hope it helps someone:)