# C# Dependency injection for Abstract class in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created one Parent library where in, I have a abstract class,and I have another child library where I have inherited the parent library, now I'm consuming this child library in web API controller, so, I would be consuming this in service layer,however, I'm not sure how to use it correctly, secondly I have all, the methods inside this library as protected, please guide how to do dependency injection for abstract class or do I need to create another interface or something for DI?

```
Code:

// Parent library
public abstract class Page
{
       protected abstract void ImplementAbstractMethod();
}

// Child library
public class ImplementPage : Page
{
    protected override void ImplementAbstractMethod()
     {
        // Implementation... 
     }
}


// Web API 
public class ServiceController 
{
    public ServiceController( ????) // How to do dependency injection, should I use abstract class, if yes then how to consume protected method, or, do I need to make it public?
    {
     }
}

// Or In business layer

public class Service
{
    public Service( ????) // How to do dependency injection, should I use abstract class, if yes then how to consume protected method, or, should I inherit the child library??
    {
     }
}
```

Comment: You should use the base classes only in the same child and provide other methods publicly to other consumers and put the `ImplementPage` in the `DI Container` and inject it into your controller

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh You mean something like this  public ServiceController(Page pg) ??

Comment: no see this maybe helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982560/asp-net-core-constructor-injection-with-inheritance

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh That's confusing, can you show it by implementing it in my use case? That would be really helpful

Comment: But if you are only going to use the abstract class to create `implementation` rules, I think you should use the `interface`, otherwise, make public abstract methods in parent class `public abstract void ImplementAbstractMethod();`

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh I have marked it public, now main question is about DI?

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Is this correct in my business layer =>   public Service(Page pg)  ??

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh I need abstract class in parent library because it will have abstract methods and some base implementation, so I cannot use Interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247958/discussion-between-mysterious288-and-mohammad-aghazadeh).

Comment: in di `builder.Services.AddScoped<Page,ImplementPage>();`  in business layer `public Service(Page pg)`

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh yeah already implemented in that way.. juz want to validate, I'm in right direction.